# Can not get correct clientWidth or clientHeight with react ref

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome, dom

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.ref = React.createRef()
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { clientWidth, clientHeight } = this.ref.current
    console.log(this.ref.current)
    console.log(clientWidth, clientHeight)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div ref={this.ref} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}></div>
    )
}
```

I want to get width and height of an element

The first log contains correct values

But the second log says different

Why?

first log:

```
clientHeight:783
clientLeft:0
clientTop:0
clientWidth:1385
```

second log:

```
1920 248
```

Comment: This might be insufficient to debug the issue. I've created a simple code sandbox, which behaves as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/ppr0qxx73x. If you resize the view area you will see the width is updated as expected (check the code sandbox built-in console)

Comment: Try calling it on `componentDidUpdate`. The thing  is when you log this.ref.current, the logged object is showing mutation of the object that happened after the logging, while clientWidth and clientHeight are coimputed only once, on componentDidMount.

Comment: Chrome logger is logging the reference of the object. To understand it better, you can log it with JSON.stringify in componentDidMount

Comment: You first log is producing different output than my similar code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/8l94r1p2w8 ......................

Can you see if i am missing something.

Comment: Is this the code that you are actually using? If you have img the height might change after the image is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Now I have figured it out, chrome console log sometime is very slow,
by the time it logs, the width and height already changed.